# Link /sdcard to /usbdisk0 on Android

Tags: android, hyperlink, sd-card

Android apps usually cache data in /sdcard/Android/data/app.name/cache folder. Now I want all apps to save and load cache files to/from a USB drive automatically, without changing their source codes. When a USB drive is plugged into the phone through a [micro USB to USB adapter](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/ET-R205UBEGSTA), it's automatically mounted in /usbdisk0 - which is good. And only if I link /sdcard to /usbdisk0, things are done.

However, the following commands don't work with this error: "link failed No such file or directory".

```
ln -sf /sdcard /usbdisk0
ln -sf /storage/sdcard0 /usbdisk0
ln -sf /storage/emulated/0 /usbdisk0
```

So what's the right path for emulated sdcard on Android? How to link it to another folder? Any helps are appreciated.

Update 1: Have tried the app FolderMount which tries to link internal sdcard to a USB drive. Unfortunately, when the app is running, Google Map fails to save offline map data.

Update 2: Security is not my concern.

Comment: I doubt Android would let you do such an operation. It would have too many bad consequences

Comment: This is true for consumer electronics. However, as Android is used more and more for embedded systems, functions like the one in this post are becoming important. The security (or whatever) concerns you have can be addressed by either designers who custom Android or the larger system who embeds this Android system.

Comment: What device have you done your test on ?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 2 with Cyanogenmod.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, i don't think it's possible on such a device, even with root access

Comment: So I should change to some dev boards instead of a smartphone?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to unmount the existing sdcard and then mount the USBDrive to the location /storage/emulated/legacy (the path where my sdcard is mounted)

Comment: How to unmount an emulated (or internal) sdcard?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error ("link failed No such file or directory") tells you the truth.
If /usbdisk0 is the existing one, you have just switched the parameter.

`ln -s /usbdisk0 /sdcard/..whateverthenaveofthelinkshouldbe`

I guess you know that you have to be carefuly with operations like that.